# How to Create Button in achartEngine Bar Chart acitivity

Tags: android, android-layout, bar-chart, achartengine

I am working with charts on Android. But I am unable to create a button on the [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/) bar chart. The problem is when I create a button, it is created successfully but it appears on the first Activity (i.e. MainActivity). However, the chart is displayed on another activity, GraphicalActivity. How do I add the Button to GraphicalActivity instead?

In the manifest I called

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />//Another activity to display chart
```

In main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:text="@string/str_tv_title"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
    android:text="Next" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

It works fine, but this button shows up on the first activity e.g. MainActivity. How do I create it in the GraphicalActivity?

Attached image shows the main activity. After that it calls GraphicalActivity. So how do I add the button on GraphicalActivity instead?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created button on one activity(called MainActivity) and generated the chart in another activity using achartLibrary.

Add snippet where your chart generated...

Here is your answer siboo

Add LinearLayout to show chart in same activity of button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_chart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_btn_chart"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chartLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_chart"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000"/>
```

Java Part

Add below code after  **multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);**

```
if (mChartView == null) {
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chartLayout);
GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
layout.addView(mChartView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
else {mChartView.repaint();}
```

And remove

**Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);**

It will work...Happy Coding

Comment: i Used Same Code From : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/ .

Comment: In your reference, coded as to generate the chart in new activity using Intent like  Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

Comment: So how to add button in new activity can you tell me